# Куда пропала ссылка "Задать вопрос" в мобильной версии?

Tags: дефект, мобильная-версия

Раньше помню была, в данный момент не нахожу, приходится жать:

```
Полная версия → Задать вопрос → Мобильная версия
```

> [image: скрыншот]

Почему её убрали?

UPD:
Не влазит со всех браузеров
Телефон: Lenovo A316i
Дисплей: 4" 480х800

Comment: У меня [отображается](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAz3R.png). Может быть Вы не туда смотрите?

Comment: Ясно, не влазит, добавил скрыншот

Comment: Попробуйте в ладшафтный режим телефон перевести. Будет показывать?

Comment: Да, в ландшафтном есть, но все же хотелось бы и в портретном её видет, экран 4 дюйма, не такой уж маленький чтоб не поддерживать, как вариант прокрутку сделать там

Comment: А на enSO все кнопки помещаются? Может это проблема только русской версии.

Comment: Да, на en версии помещается, символов там меньше

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос модель телефона. У меня на 5.5" всё хорошо.

Comment: Еще можете мобильное приложение скачать на проверку. Имхо удобнее должно быть.

Comment: Приложения юзаю только для часто посещаемых сайтов, сюда я не настолько часто захожу

Comment: Попробуйте еще включать в браузере полный режим. Не на сайте, а именно в браузере. И модель всё же лучше полностью, а не только размер экрана. Я думаю, это будет полезнее для подтверждения проблемы.

Comment: В каком смысле полный режим? У меня в браузере под полным режимом имеется введу ПК user agent и соотвецтвенно сайт отображается так же как и по нажатию кнопки "Полная версия" на сайте

Comment: мобильную версию можно и на ПК включить принудительно. А в хроме прямо пункт меню такой есть "полная версия"

Comment: Мобильная версия в режиме полной версии отображается также как и мобильная версия с ПК(в полном маштабе) и разумеется кнопка влазит ибо шириной дисплея страница не ограничена, думаю подтверждений достаточно

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю сделать так:

```
.nav {
    /* height: 44px; */
    height: auto;
}

.nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Вот что получится:

[image: 320*533]

[image: 533*320]

Нормально, если ширина больше 284, а потом становится плохо:

[image: 284]

[image: 200]

Это можно было бы поправить так:

```
.nav ul {
    /* ... */
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Но я не уверен, что это хорошая идея (хотя при нормальной ширине всё останется как раньше):

[image: 200 + break]

[image: 100 + break]

Comment: Последний случай напомнил бегущие символы из Матрицы :)

Comment: @alexolut, надо последний пункт на символ длиннее или короче...

Comment: Это ещё зачем ?

Comment: @alexolut, чтоб он по строкам с остальными выровнялся :)

Comment: Для какой картинки это применимо?

Comment: @alexolut, для последней, конечно)))

Comment: А-а-а... чтобы по горизонтали в одну линию буквы выстроились. Понятно. В таком случае появятся пункты: "оМаЗза", "песнот", "рттать", "окнквв" и "сиииео" :)

Answer (score 2):

Упомянутую проблему можно повторить и на обычном ПК, путём уменьшения ширины окна браузера, например в FF получилось уменьшить до ~300px:

> [image: FF300]

Если окно чуть раздвинуть (+70px) - ссылка "Задать вопрос" появляется:

> [image: FF370]

Т.о. дело не только в кол-ве пикселей, но, вероятно, и в их плотности на экране.

Также удалось повторить на телефоне. Когда открыта главная - всё нормально:

> [image: main page]

Есть нажать на любую из ссылок в верхней части или выбрать любой вопрос, то поле "задать вопрос" исчезает:

> [image: question]

Проблему, как мне кажется можно решить несколькими способами:

1. Изменить название пунктов меню, чтобы они содержали меньше букв.
2. Убрать пункт "Без ответа", например его вообще нет на enSO:

   > [image: enSO]

   но вместо него (хоть и в другой позиции) есть пункт "Jobs".
3. Адаптировать стиль меню, чтобы все ссылки помещались при любой ширине, т.е. просто уменьшать масштаб текста в крайних случаях.

Наиболее правильным вариантом мне кажется последний. Если кто знает как это будет проще всего реализовать в коде - пожалуйста, дополните ответ.

Comment: 4. Разрешить перенос пунктов меню на новую строку.

Comment: 5. Разрешить горизонтальный скролл

Comment: @PavelMayorov, 4 - он и так разрешён. Только вот контейнер по высоте ограничен одной строкой))

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда это не называется "разрешен"

Comment: @PavelMayorov, называется, потому что последний пункт (когда его не видно) как раз-таки находится на второй строке :D

Answer (score -2):

z-index проверьте, возможно наложение блоков

Comment: Ну нет же... И вообще, какое ещё наложение??